# Authenticating with Windows Azure Active Directory directly without opening web browser

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, securestring, azure-active-directory

I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141640/how-to-validate-azure-active-directory-user-credential) and [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/246e4244-5a6c-43a8-a05d-88744196740c/azure-ad-azure-acs-windows-8-xaml-app), but couldn't get the problem fixed.

Below code demonstrates how to perform the WAAD authentication using web browser:

```
AuthenticationContext auth = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + myDomain);
AuthenticationResult result = auth.AcquireToken(resource, clientID, resourceAppIDURI);
```

This opens a browser and user is asked to enter the details which works fine.

However, I have a GUI client, which can take username/password/domain on its own. So the intention is to collect the details from GUI client and directly provide to the WAAD server and get the user authenticated.

How to do that?

Just looking at the overloads of `AcquireToken()`, I did get some clue (this can be wrong as well):

```
AuthenticationResult AcquireToken (string resource, Credential credential);
```

and

```
AuthenticationResult AcquireToken (string authorizationCode, string redirectUri, ClientCredential credential);
```

But I fail to understand, how to create the `class ClientCredential` (subclass of `Credential`). Important to note that this class belongs to the `namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication`.
Below are its constructors:

```
ClientCredential(string clientId, SecureString secureClientSecret);
ClientCredential(string clientId, string clientSecret);
```

Searching online, I couldn't get much answers, I did get [this link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Multi-Tenant-Cloud-8015b84b). But again the part of `SecureString` is a mystery to me. How the username/password/domain can be communicated using `SecureString`?

Answer (score 4):

The older version of AAL supported this.  However, it was removed about 2-3 months ago (as well as the sample showing it).  Authentication of users now can only be achieved through a browser authentication window.

I'm not 100% sure, but I *think* the motivation is to create a standard/consistent login experience (for the end-users).  If you're on a Windows 8 application, then the WebAuthenticationBroker handles this and users will recognize this for all Windows 8 applications.  If you're a web application, then the AzureAD login page is presented and is recognizable.

Comment: Can you explain the last 2 sentences in more detail? I am fairly new to this. We are already able to implement the authentication using web browser and manual entry of username/password. Would really appreciate, if you can demonstrate some work-around to this problem in bit more detail.

Comment: @iammilind, it's perhaps too late to reply to your question but might help someone landing here - When you click on login in your web application, it is directed to https://login.microsoftonline.com (instance) with your tenant details in the URL. You can have your branding on this page but it is still recognizable to all the users. Once the users authenticates themselves, they are redirected to your app (Reply URL provided in the application on Azure). Hope this help!

Comment: @sandiejat Hi, but what should happen I am connecting from a desktop app (WinForm) using REST API client to Azure API App? Currently I am getting 401 not authorized when trying to access from application, but if I open it from browser - everything seams to be working (here is my SO question in case if you can help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568523/add-rest-api-client-not-working-if-appservice-authentication-is-set-to-on

Answer (score 2):

The `ClientCredential` overload of `AcquireToken` that you found is for you to use a client id and secret key to authenticate (so that customers don't have to share their username and password).

Create a "web application" in the WAAD and the application will be given a client id guid. This is the first parameter in your `ClientCredential()` constructor.

To get the second parameter, add a key to your WAAD web application.

You might want to update to the latest version of AAL, which is now known as ADAL. [NuGet link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/1.0.3)